# Entity Framework 4.1 Dynamically Generated Tables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, orm, entity-framework-4, entity

I have two models; User and Client. A user can have many clients and a client has one user. The project manager **insists** each users clients to be in a separate **table** so I must dynamically generate new tables for each user that is created. For example user ABC will have a new table called ABC_Clients, user XXX will have a separate table called XXX_Clients and so forth. My question: how do I do this with Entity Framework? I can simply execute a procedure to create the new table and do an manual query with `ExecuteStoreQuery()` but it doesn't seem to pull relationships back (i.e. Lazy Load), do I have to construct my query in a certain way or something?

Comment: the guy needs to learn about RDBMS design basics :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is excellent design. It will be really easy to use and really nice to maintain. Congratulate your manager and tell him to do his job and let you do yours. Project manager is not architect and most often it is person with poor technical knowledge.

There is no way to support this with EF. You must do it completely with SQL (actually dynamic SQL in this case) and old ADO.NET. `ExecuteStoreQuery` never returns relations - it is not able to do that. Lazy loading cannot work as well because standard lazy loading is based on static database structure mapped with Entity framework. Your `Client` entity cannot be mapped by EF because it demands that each entity will be mapped only once (= to one table or set of related tables in case of inheritance or splitting). Your `Client` entity would need to be mapped as many times as you have users in your `User` table.

Comment: I agree. He's actually a developer himself and says hes speaking from "experience": if you drop the clients table my mistake then everybody is affected where as if they are separated out and one client table is dropped by mistake it only affects one users clients. I see where he is coming from but that's what database backups are for, etc. Anyway I thought as much re. the question, thanks :-)

Comment: Drop the table by mistake? What is that? That cannot happen in normal application architecture but it can indeed happen in your architecture where your application must have permissions to drop and create tables.

Comment: @eth0 if you have some spare time post this design on [The Daily WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/)

Comment: @LadislavMrnka What should we do if there is an application which add/delete db columns from the database at runtime ?

Comment: @HoussamHamdan: You should not use EF in such case.